# Read big file in python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read a large file in Python. And for some reason it does not work for me. This is the code I tried and it did not work

Anyone know what the problem is with the code?

```
  myFile = open("myfile.txt", "r")
        lines = phoneFile.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if userMessage in line:
                alltheline = line.split(":")
                return alltheline[0]
        return "not found"
```

The problem is not with closing the file!
When it enters the for loop it throws an exeption

i found the problem, jast add to the open line

```
encoding="utf8"
```

Comment: what does "it doesnt work for me" mean? thats not really a helpful description. Can you tell us what doesnt work, does it give an error, does it just hang, does it return the wrong result?

Comment: what is the userMessage?

Comment: you put the result of *open* in *myFile* but after you read using *phoneFile*, why not using *myFile* or why showing *myFile* assignment if it is useless here ?

Comment: out of that I encourage you to use *with* (`with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myFile:`)

Comment: what file are you trying to read from, lets start with that? myFile or phoneFile?

Comment: change phoneFile to myFile unless you are trying to read from phoneFile? then change myFile to phoneFile

Comment: you mistyped something to get the error, or it doesn't like what is in the file so what is in the file? and what is the difference between myFile and phoneFile

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Changed Phone file to my file as you were trying to read something else instead of the opened file. I also added `myFile.close()` to close the file when you are done.

```
 myFile = open("myfile.txt", "r")
 lines = myFile.readlines()
 for line in lines:
     if userMessage in line:
           alltheline = line.split(":")
           return alltheline[0]
 myFile.close()
 return "not found"
```

**Or by using the with statement, this allows us to open the file and then close it automatically once we are done instead of using myFile.close() to do it for us**

```
   with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as myFile:
        for line in myFile:
            if userMessage in line:
               alltheline = line.split(":")
               return alltheline[0]
        return "not found"
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation otherwise this might seriously confuse a programmer new to python.

Comment: I also encourage you to explain why the second proposal is much better thanks to the *with* and the smaller used memory size. The more you say the better it is

Comment: close the file still not working.

Comment: which one are you using?: with statement or above?

Comment: is there an error or anything or does it not work?. Can you explain the problem?

Comment: throws error in this line " lines = phoneFile.readlines()"

Comment: what even is phoneFile? = are you not reading MyFile but phonefile? and what is the error, put the whole thing

Comment: solved - encoding="utf8" this what i forget

Comment: what file are you trying to read from, lets start with that? myFile or phoneFile?